# How move controllers in subfolders

Tags: playframework-2.1

i'm using play framework 2.1 and i got a strange error.
I'm trying to move controllers in subfolders, es:

> controllers->
>   - Application.java
>   - pages ->
>   - - - -Index.java
>   - - - -Second.java

and in routes i have:

> GET / controllers.pages.Index.main();

error:

> value main is not a member of object controllers.pages.Index

It's a bug? regards Nicola

**SOLVED**
bug found: you cannot access to methods of parent class, you have to override them:

```
public static Result main(String page, String method)
{
    return ParentClass.main(page,method);
}
```

Comment: Is your Index.java file within the controllers.pages package?

Comment: yes,seems a bug extending another controller https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/QpAy2anCs_g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it was fixed in final Play 2.1 (or I missed something) - the route to method which is not 'overriden' in child class still returns error.

AFAIK in Java real overriding of static methods isn't possible at all.

Anyway... remember that all actions by design are a static methods so, you don't need to use the route to `Child.methodOfParent()` while you can just use `Parent.methodOfParent()`, something you are showing as a solution should be rather considered as `overloading` instead of `overriding`.

On the other hand, from my point of view I'd rather suggest to do not use this pattern at all. Play's actions should be separate methods which does its job independently from other actions, and if you need to use the (almost) same functionality in both actions probably it would be better concept to use other static method (not an action) ie. in new `utils` package to process body of both actions with params. IMHO it will be just safer approach, as you can see - there are still some 'unknowns'.

Comment: this is why i need to extend controllers: https://github.com/jstar88/LibreTitan/blob/master/conf/routes . hope you appreciate the style